# getdate with time 2359

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running a procedure where I use yesterday's date through `DATEADD(day,-1,getdate())`. The challenge is that my procedure runs at 1:30 at night, and it then returns the data like

```
 2014-12-09 01 30
```

I need it to return something like `2014-12-09 23 59`, because i have a `DATETIME` column. Does anyone have an idea, how to do that?

Comment: Where is your procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used something like below in an SP :

```
SELECT Cast(Getdate()-1 AS DATE)
       + Cast('23:59:00' AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun - but this would work, but only with a datetime datatype in SQL Server:

```
SELECT CAST((FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT))) -0.0006944444 AS DATETIME)
```

This gives you yesterday 23:59:00

In SQL Server the DATETIME datatype is internally handled like a float, so by casting it to float and flooring it, it returns the value for datetime wich just contains the date portion. Then I subtract the float number equivalent to a minute and cast it back as a datetime

A more correct way would however properly be to use the appropiate functions, so:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, - 1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

This calculates the current date without time portion and then subtracts one minute.

Comment: Thx. I might use the first just to tip the other guys here off a little

Comment: @Zeb please remember to mark a post as answer if it has solved an issue, to show your question is answered. :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be:

```
SELECT dateadd(minute,-1,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand why you want 23:59 of previous day, but you can use something like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))))
```

Comment: Thx. This gave me 2 days before.